# using React hooks in hierarchy

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, subcomponent

I am new in react and have developed quite few functional components in my new react app that are getting called in loops. One of child component, renders radio button. On selecting the option of radio button, I need to call webapi and update the state in parent App.js. I have been looking into hooks and not been able to use built-in so far, thinking of implementing a custom hook. Can you please suggest the best approach

Comment: Show us what you did

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow. Please do review [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and attempt this on your own prior to providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt. If you've an issue describe as accurately as possible the issue, error messages, and debugging done.

Comment: json response, is like this

Comment: Json is like the following

|
|-Questionaire
    |--Topics
           |--Questions (for each topic)
           |--Answer Options( corresponding to each question)
            
on click of selected option, api call would get full json with another question and option

Cant show the code snippet here but I have created function components ,  
topics.map(topic => questions)
questions.map(ques => ques description)
options.map(option => each option with onclick event that is using hooks)

Answer (score 0):

Well, custom hooks are based on the hooks provided by react. Mostly `useEffect` and `useState`. I don't think you need more than that to call an API and update state in the parent component.

Here's the approach that is most common:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  const onClick = () => {
    // Call API here and update state
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setData(json);
      });
  };

  return <Options onClick={onClick} data={data} />;
}

function Options({ data, onClick }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Data: </h4>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
      <input type="radio" onClick={onClick} />
    </div>
  );
}
```